# Registering share intents on Google Glass

Tags: share, google-glass, google-gdk

Is there a way to to register my share intent so that in the normal Glass photo app I can register a card with my own Activity, i.e. `share with x`? This is straightforward in Android but doesn't seem to translate to Google Glass.

This is what I am trying now:

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.x.ShareActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/x" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. The "share with x" screen only shows Glass contacts (See : https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/contacts) At this time, only glasswares using Mirror Api can register them self as a contact.
There is no way for the **default** camera app (that was invoked directly) to share a photo with your GDK app at this moment.